# Multicolumns tables in LaTeX writing are not in correct order

Tags: charts, latex

I am writing an article and the template is in LaTeX, and I need to insert a multicolumn table, the problem is, I have knowledgement just with the basics about LaTeX writing and i am finding some trouble with the organisation of the columns.

This is how the table should look like (image inside Word doc): [Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILX09.png)

And this is how the code that i am using is being compiled inside LaTeX: [LaTeX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMcf6.png)

Here is the code:

```
\begin{table*}[!htb]

\centering%

\caption{Parâmetros obtidos para o ajuste utilizando o modelo de Langmuir.}%

\label{tab:resul}

\centering%

\begin{tabular}{c c c c}

\hline

Modelo de Langmuir: 

\begin{minipage}{7cm}{\begin{equation}\label{eq:Uxy}

\frac{\\Qmax\ K_L Ceq}{\\1\ +K_L Ceq} = Qe

\end{equation}}

\end{minipage} \\

\cline{1-4}

\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{HDL Calc}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{HDL SDS Calc}} \\

\hline

Qmax & K(L/mg) & Qmax(mg/g) & K(L/mg)\\

\hline

690,6 & 0,011 & 132,3 & 0,136\\

\bottomrule

\addlinespace

\end{tabular}

\fonte{Autoria própria (2021).}

\end{table*}
```

Any help with the code?

Comment: Can you please make a compileable [mre] including the documentclass and packages necessary to compile your code fragement

Comment: Im sorry for not doing it before, i am new. Thank you for the comprehension.
I did a project inside overleaf, here is the link: https://www.overleaf.com/1247375849jqcfrjwzsmvw

Comment: Unfortunatly your code does not compile. What package did you mean to load in l. 17?

Comment: If I remove this syntax error, I do get a nicely centred multicolumn https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifIfi.png